# Query to select by number of associated objects

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables that look like the following:

```
Orders
------
id
tracking_number

ShippingLogs
------
tracking_number
created_at
stage
```

I would like to select the IDs of Orders that have ONLY ONE ShippingLog associated with it, and the stage of the ShippingLog must be `error`. If it has two ShippingLog entries, I don't want it. If it has one ShippingLog bug its stage is `shipped`, I don't want it.

This is what I have, and it doesn't work, and I know why (it finds the log with the error, but has no way of knowing if there are others). I just don't really know how to get it the way I need it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    orders.id, shipping_logs.created_at, COUNT(shipping_logs.*)
FROM
    orders
JOIN
    shipping_logs ON orders.tracking_number = shipping_logs.tracking_number
WHERE
    shipping_logs.created_at BETWEEN '2021-01-01 23:40:00'::timestamp AND '2021-01-26 23:40:00'::timestamp AND shipping_logs.stage = 'error'

GROUP BY
    orders.id, shipping_logs.created_at
HAVING
    COUNT(shipping_logs.*) = 1
ORDER BY
    orders.id, shipping_logs.created_at DESC;
```

Comment: If it has two shipping_log entries, you say you want to ignore the order, but the condition set on shipping_logs.created_at will prevent it from finding these extra shipping_log entries you want to filter on if they're outside of the date range, so I'm not sure what you want. Do you want the row with error to be inside the date range, but the other rows could have any date? Or something else?

Comment: Also is there a PK in table shipping_logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain every column from the join of the two tables given your requirements, then I would suggest using `COUNT` here as an analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT o.id, sl.created_at,
           COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY o.id) num_logs,
           COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE sl.stage <> 'error')
                    OVER (PARTITION BY o.id) non_error_cnt
    FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN shipping_logs sl ON sl.tracking_number = o.tracking_number
    WHERE sl.created_at BETWEEN '2021-01-01 23:40:00'::timestamp AND
                                '2021-01-26 23:40:00'::timestamp
)

SELECT id AS order_id, created_at
FROM cte
WHERE num_logs = 1 AND non_error_cnt = 0
ORDER BY id, created_at DESC;
```

Comment: Tim, you beautiful son of a--- thank you!